# Double Dynamic Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, sql, search, select, drop-down-menu

I am making a 'search engine' for my database and I am limiting queries through the use of dropdowns as the values, so no wrong searches can be made. In short the searches will be done based on the columns and values. In this question I have reduced the amount of columns to three, as if you can help me make work 2, then hopefully I will understand to do myself more.

First dropdown (column), corresponding dropdown with the new options (value).
Second dropdown (column), corresponding dropdown with the new options (value).

Indeed the first and second dropdown queries have the same column names, because we want to match two queries simaltaniously.

Current code: The first is a dropdown already, and it works perfectly. However, I tried a lot to make the second one a dropdown (which is easy), but then make it work like the first one, it didn't succeed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setOptions(chosen) {
        var selbox = document.search.findone;

        selbox.options.length = 0;
        if (chosen == " ") {
            selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');
        }
        if (chosen == "SHIPPINGLINE") {
            selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('MSC','MSC');
            selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('first choice - option two','onetwo');
        }
        if (chosen == "POL") {
            selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('HONG KONG','HONG KONG');
            selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('SHANGHAI','SHANGHAI');
        }
        if (chosen == "POD") {
            selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('HAMBURG','HAMBURG');
            selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('LE HAVRE','LE HAVRE');
        }
    }
</script>
```

and further

```
<div id="searchzone">
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <form name="search" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
        <Select NAME="fieldone"   onchange="setOptions(document.search.fieldone.options[document.search.fieldone.selectedInde    x].value);" id="fieldone">
            <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
            <option VALUE="SHIPPINGLINE">SHIPPING LINE</option>
            <option VALUE="POL">POL</option>
            <option VALUE="POD">POD</option>
        </Select>
        <Select NAME="findone" />

        <option value=" " selected="selected">Please select the category on the left first.</option>
        </select>

    <br />
    <br />
        <Select NAME="fieldtwo">
            <option VALUE="SHIPPINGLINE">SHIPPING LINE</option>
            <option VALUE="POL">POL</option>
            <option VALUE="POD">POD</option>
        </Select>
        <input type="text" name="findtwo" />
        <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
```

maybe relevant for you to know, this is my sql query, it works fine :)

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE upper($fieldone) LIKE'%$findone%' AND upper($fieldtwo) LIKE'%$findtwo%'");
```

I would appreciate it a lot if you can help me out, if you need any other information, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/REzdM/)

```
var opts = {
    "SHIPPINGLINE":[
        {text:"MSC",value:"MSC"},
        {text:"first choice - option two",value:"onetwo"}
        ],
    "POL":[
        { text:"HONG KONG",value:"HONGKONG"},
        { text:"SHANGHAI", value:"SHANGHAI"}
       ],
    "POD":[
        { text:"HAMBURG",value:"HAMBURG"},
        { text:"LE HAVRE", value:"LE HAVRE"}
       ]

}

function changeOther(sel) {
    var selbox = document.getElementById("find"+sel.id.replace("field",""));
    console.log(selbox.id)
      selbox.options.length = 0;
      var val = sel.value;
      if (val=="") {
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options to the left first','');
        return;
      }
      for (var opt = opts[val],i=0; i<opt.length;i++) {
         selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option(opt[i].text,opt[i].value);
      }

}

window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById("fieldone").onchange=document.getElementById("fieldtwo").onchange=function() {
        changeOther(this);
   }      
}
```

Comment: Currently my code is working, it is one dropdown menu with it's conditional dropdown menu (e.g. Select: SHIPPING LINE, then in the conditional dropdown you can select MSC or first choice - option two). 

The next one (fieldtwo) is at the moment a textfield, I want this to be exactly the same dropdown as fieldone. I don't know how to explain it better. Let me know if you want more details? :) Thanks for replying btw!

Comment: In your fiddle, you got it right, that is how it is right now. What I want is that the textfield is also a dropdown, like the first one. The problem I am encountering, trying to do it myself, is that the value of the first one somehow mixes up with the second one, no matter how I put the conditions. :)

Comment: I have made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Cma7p/3/ maybe it will make it more clear what I try to achieve.

Comment: So what are the values for the 3rd drop down? I assume you want some options if I choose HAMBURG in the second dropdown? In your fiddle you just repeat the selects. Can you modify it to show the actual HTML you need?

Comment: The goals is to match fetch data from the SQL database, with values from two different columns, to match data. In example in the first dropdown I will choose POL: SHANGHAI. In the second dropdown I will choose POD then HAMBURG. Then since my SQL is:      $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE upper($fieldone) LIKE'%$findone%' AND upper($fieldtwo) LIKE'%$findtwo%'"); it will match data and fetch based on those dropdowns. Thanks for helping out again :), please let me know if u need more info!

Comment: The only  thing I need help with is to make the dropdown work :), can you please help with that?

Comment: I do not understand. In your first dropdown you have 3 choices, Shipping, pol and pod. When I choose POL, I get HONGKONG and SHANGHAI in the SECOND drop down. What happens to the THIRD drop down??? You want to AJAX the values in from the server?

Comment: Is it possible to talk on Skype? :) indertje.singh it would be amazing. I think this is too easy for you. To me I see two dropdowns on the left, two on the right. Both on left and right have exactly the same things. The only difference is their name attribute, which I use to query the database. So the left side on top has  SHIPPINGLINE, POL and POD, the left side bottom also has SHIPPINGLINE, POL and POD. But since the name attribute is different, (fieldone <this is the left side dropdown, findone <this is the right side dropdown, same goes for fieldtwo and findtwo).

Comment: Ah I think you got me the wrong way. I want to fill the 2nd with the value of the first. And the 4th with the value of the 3rd. The values of the 1st and the 3rd are identical. But, I want to be able to choose a different value for 3, than for 1. For example for 1 I would choose POL, and for 3 I would choose POD. Then in 2 I will put SHANGHAI and in 4 I will put HAMBURG. Means I choose different things for 2 and 4. It sounds a lot more complicated than it is. Please keep posting :) I really appreciate it a lot..

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I wanted (just removed the textfield tho). Thanks a lot for your help :).